# How to reset password for a hosted app at Heroku sever?

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

I hope you are best with your health.
I am new to this thing and wants community help.

I am stuck in a problem that my friends have made a web app which was hosted at Heroku server. Now, we didn't remember the password of it. How we can reset that? Is there any clue?

Please help.

Link to the app:
http://alpharabi-nkii-tell.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you talking about resetting your _Heroku_ password, or resetting passwords in some application you've deployed _to_ Heroku? In the latter case, how can we possibly answer that without knowing how you built your application? That it's hosted on Heroku is entirely irrelevant in that case. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use forgot password option, click on the button and follow the step
[image]

Comment: Its too obvious, I had done a hit on "forgot your password" but didn't find a clue. Anyways thanks.

Comment: @UmairHanif Tumhari kus main fire